# How to trigger a data insert into Mongo DB while data is inserted in another SQL DB

Tags: oracle, mongodb

My requirement is to insert data into a Mongo DB when data is inserted to another Oracle DB table. I would like to know how to trigger this insert. Any modifications in Oracle Tables must be reflected in the Mongo DB also. Both the Databases are in different hosts. Kindly advise.

Comment: The only solution I could think of is to modify the application to make each function which performs an SQL INSERT and SQL UPDATE to also perform an equivalent operation to a MongoDB database. I don't know any middleware which can do this automatically. It might be hard to do, because not every SQL operation has a strict 1:1 equivalent in MongoDB and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

It may be some heavy-lifing up front, but the "right" approach is probably to use something like GoldenGate (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html), which allows you to detect all changes to base table and propagate to remote (even non-Oracle) database in preferred manner.

Comment: Thanks guys for your valuable feedback.